# Ubuntu freezing every second

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, freeze

I recently installed Ubuntu as a second OS. Everything worked fine until I got a new PC case. I moved all my hardware to this new case (no changes). My windows worked the same as before but my Ubuntu started to lag every second. When I'm typing (like this post) the system freezes after every 2/3 words and after the short freeze (about 1 second) the words I typed appear. The same when I'm scrolling through a webpage, it sometimes just stops scrolling and then jumps to the place where I should be. I'm also listening at the same moment and that doesn't lag. The system is a pretty decent setup (i7-6700k and a nvidia 1080)

**Now comes the weird part.** I tried to check if I could see any weird behavior in System Monitor and when I have that open the lag is a lot less. It still appears sometimes but you don't even notice it.

Any idea what this could be?

`free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3,2Gi       9,2Gi        47Mi       3,1Gi        12Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

`sysctl vm.swappiness`:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

`grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`sudo swapon -s`:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

[image: Disk]
*(Other disks are for my Windows install)*

[image: SMART Data & Test]

Comment: Did you check your logs?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo swapon -s` and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. It's a scrollable window so it may need two screenshots. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I added the information you asked for.

Comment: Just wondering...  Would you clarify how long between your installation of Ubuntu and moving your system to the new case?  Just curious how long was it "working".  During that time and since using the new case, you didn't upgrade Ubuntu?  Is the new case bigger?  Any chance of overheating or something loose, etc.?

Comment: @Ray I installed Ubuntu 1 or 2 months before moving to the new case. I haven't upgrade Ubuntu since the install. Overheating shouldn't be a problem. My CPU is about 20 degrees celcius on average. Overall temp is max 30 degrees celcius.

Comment: @BartBergmans Thanks for the data. Two more questions for you before I put together an initial answer. Did you install a new power supply, or reuse the old one? Are the two disks from the prior case? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your motherboard.

Comment: @heynnema It's exactly the same PSU and disks that I was using in the last case. The bios version is 1.00. The motherboard is a MSI Z170A Gaming Pro Carbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nvidia**

Nvidia GTX 1080

Purge the **Nvidia server** driver that you have installed now, and assure that you have the latest Nvidia driver 465.27, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

**SWAP**

A 2G /swapfile is too small. Let's increase it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**BIOS**

MSI Z170A Gaming Pro Carbon

You have a really old BIOS 1.00, from 2015. There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.A0, from 7/13/18, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/z170a-gaming-pro-carbon).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for still helping me! I updated the BIOS and increased the swapfile size. I couldn't install the nvidia driver. Probably because I have Nvidia X Server running. (Not really sure what the difference is) The Nvidia X Server has Nvidia Driver 460.56.

Comment: @BartBergmans Good job! Let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: The freezes still occur. Could it be a BIOS setting maybe? That's the only thing I imagine that could've been changed when moving to a new case. Although the settings should be saved if the motherboard doesn't have power.

Comment: @BartBergmansk Let's reset the Power Manager. Shutdown the computer. Depress and hold the power button for 30 seconds. Then boot the computer and see if there's any improvement. If not, I'll have to look at /var/log/syslog. Lastly, edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @BartBergmans Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I tried to make a bootable usb for memtest but it won't run...

Comment: the output of the memory command can be found here: https://pastebin.com/P9Pm2c8C

Comment: the output of the syslog can be found here: https://pastebin.com/9hnLmY29

Comment: @BartBergmans How did you try and create the bootable `memtest` USB? Do you know how to add `nomodeset` by editing the GRUB menu at boot time? You're not running a server, are you? If not, then the Nvidia Server video driver would be wrong... I see a LOT of Nvidia activity in syslog...

Comment: I used the imageUSB.exe that was delivered with memtest download. I'm not running a server. Can I safely remove the nvidia server video driver and install the "regular" driver?

Comment: @BartBergmans To create the `memtest` USB, either try `Rufus` in Windows, or `Startup Disk Creator` in Ubuntu. Yes, you should purge Nvidia server, and install the standard driver I quoted.

Comment: @BartBergmans Status please...

Comment: sorry I was quite busy with work the past few days. I already created the USB using Rufus. I'll run it tonight.

Comment: I also get the "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device" error when using the USB I created using Rufus

Comment: After I did:
```sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*```
```sudo apt-get autoremove```

I think everything works properly now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BartBergmans Good news. Did you install the regular Nvidia software?

Comment: I tried to do that but that didn't work. When I look at Software & Updates it still says that it's using X.Org X server. https://imgur.com/Z6zVpyi But if it works, i'm happy

Comment: @BartBergmans But you're not using ANY of the features of your expensive Nvidia card that way. What happened when you tried to install the driver in my link? What happens if you click on the top choice in S&U?

Comment: I only use the features of my card when gaming on my Windows install. When I tried to install it the first time it said it detected another driver that was installed a different way. And when I run it now it says that nouveau is installed and is not compatible with this driver installer.

Comment: When I pick the top choice it gives me an error: pk-client-error-quark: E: dpkg was intterupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem (281)

Comment: @BartBergmans Did you do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then try the top choice in S&U again? Did you manually try to install the driver from my link?

Comment: When I do that I get the error: pk-client-error-quark: Error while installing package: 0.7812 (313)

Comment: When I try to install the driver I get the following errors:
https://imgur.com/a/5EdDCUA

Comment: @BartBergmans What happens when you do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: It could also be your cpu is being throttled.  Try adjusting your power profile with ubuntu package indicator-cpufreq or the gnome shell extension cpufreq